# Parsing blank XML tags with LXML and Python

Tags: python, xml, parsing, xml-parsing

When parsing XML documents in the format of:

```
<Car>
    <Color>Blue</Color>
    <Make>Chevy</Make>
    <Model>Camaro</Model>
</Car>
```

I use the following code:

```
carData = element.xpath('//Root/Foo/Bar/Car/node()[text()]')
parsedCarData = [{field.tag: field.text for field in carData} for action in carData]
print parsedCarData[0]['Color'] #Blue
```

This code will not work if a tag is empty such as :

```
<Car>
    <Color>Blue</Color>
    <Make>Chevy</Make>
    <Model/>
</Car>
```

Using the same code as above:

```
carData = element.xpath('//Root/Foo/Bar/Car/node()[text()]')
parsedCarData = [{field.tag: field.text for field in carData} for action in carData]
print parsedCarData[0]['Model'] #Key Error
```

How would I parse this blank tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're putting in a `[text()]` filter which explicitly asks only for elements which have text nodes them... and then you're unhappy when it doesn't give you elements without text nodes?

Leave that filter out, and you'll get your model element:

```
>>> s='''
... <root>
...   <Car>
...     <Color>Blue</Color>
...     <Make>Chevy</Make>
...     <Model/>
...   </Car>
... </root>'''
>>> e = lxml.etree.fromstring(s)
>>> carData = e.xpath('Car/node()')
>>> carData
[<Element Color at 0x23a5460>, <Element Make at 0x23a54b0>, <Element Model at 0x23a5500>]
>>> dict(((e.tag, e.text) for e in carData))
{'Color': 'Blue', 'Make': 'Chevy', 'Model': None}
```

That said -- if your immediate goal is to iterate over the nodes in the tree, you might consider using `lxml.etree.iterparse()` instead, which will avoid trying to build a full DOM tree in memory and otherwise be much more efficient than building a tree and then iterating over it with XPath. (Think SAX, but without the insane and painful API).

Implementing with `iterparse` could look like this:

```
def get_cars(infile):
    in_car = False
    current_car = {}
    for (event, element) in lxml.etree.iterparse(infile, events=('start', 'end')):
        if event == 'start':
            if element.tag == 'Car':
                in_car = True
                current_car = {}
            continue
        if not in_car: continue
        if element.tag == 'Car':
            yield current_car
            continue
        current_car[element.tag] = element.text

for car in get_cars(infile = cStringIO.StringIO('''<root><Car><Color>Blue</Color><Make>Chevy</Make><Model/></Car></root>''')):
  print car
```

...it's more code, but (if we weren't using StringIO for the example) it could process a file much larger than could fit in memory.

Comment: Right now I am doing an `element = etree.parse(xmlfile)`. How would iterparse change my existing code base?

Comment: @lodkkx Using iterparse looks something like: `for (event_type, element) in lxml.etree.iterparse(xmlfile): ...`, deciding what action to take with each element in turn (typically by inspecting its tag).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there's a better solution built inside lxml, but you could just use [`.get()`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get):

```
print parsedCarData[0].get('Model', '')
```

Answer (score 0):

I would catch the exception:

```
try:
    print parsedCarData[0]['Model']
except KeyError:
    print 'No model specified'
```

Exceptions in Python aren't exceptional in the same sense as in other languages, where they are more strictly linked to error conditions. Instead they are frequently part of the normal usage of modules, by design. An iterator raises `StopIteration` to signal it has reached the end of the iteration, for example.

Edit: If you're sure only this item can be empty @CharlesDuffy has it right in that using `get()` is probably better. But in general I'd consider using exceptions for handling diverse exceptional output easily.

Comment: Using `parsedCarModel[0].get('Model')` to avoid the exception (returning `None` in the not-found case) is both shorter and faster than raising and handling an exception... though I think this is silly when removing an unnecessary restriction from the XPath query would make this moot in the first place.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: that's true, but I think this approach has advantages. I usually use try/except blocks to wrap lines in which I make several assumptions about the input across several of them. In that case using exceptions seems more natural than changing every line. Also, often you'd have to handle None with an if anyway.

Answer (score -1):

The solution: use a `try/except` block to catch the key error.

Comment: The error only happens in the first place because he's filtering out the elements with no text. Why catch it when you could avoid it, making your code shorter in the process?!

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I assume OP has some reason for doing this, perhaps that he is using the datastructure created elsewhere.

Comment: Yes, but the structure is fine -- it's the filter he's using to retrieve portions of the structure which isn't, and that part is clearly his code.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Right, but this way, he can explicitly handle that case in whatever way is appropriate.