# Replacing None object with a Null when parsing XML with Python and LXML

Tags: python, mysql, xml, parsing, lxml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Parsing blank XML tags with LXML and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9620164/parsing-blank-xml-tags-with-lxml-and-python)

Given the following XML file:

```
<Car>
    <Color>Blue</Color>
    <Make>Chevy</Make>
    <Model/>
</Car>
```

and using the following code:

```
Car = element.xpath('//Root/Foo/Bar/Car/node()')
parsedCarData = [{field.tag: field.text for field in Car} for action in Car]
```

How can I replace key values of type `None` with a blank string so I can use parsed key values into a MySQL statement.

**My Attempt - Thanks to Marcin**
Using a turnary seemed to work

```
parsedCars = [{field.tag: field.text if isinstance(field.text,str) else '' for field in Cars} for action in Cars]
```

For my cases it has always evaluated as true.However when outputting a previous None type is outputs twice. Improvements are welcome!

Comment: Learn python. Do not try to get SO to write every single piece of your code.

Comment: Also, nice job downvoting my answer on your other question.

Comment: This is your third question about the same piece of code.

Comment: SO isn't here to write your code for you.

Comment: Took your advice, tell me what you think.

Comment: It's more customary to put your attempt in your question, and explain why you're not satisfied with it. But, if you're satisfied with it, great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your requirement, you might be better off filtering on `is None`, but in practice, I doubt this will make a difference:

```
parsedCars = [{field.tag: field.text if field.text is not None else '' for field in Cars} for action in Cars]
```

You should probably use `basestr` instead of `str`, though, because your code will replace all instances of `unicode` with `''`, should lxml ever switch to unicode.